# WP | Dequeque Styles from Calculated Fields Form

Tags: wordpress, plugins

My wp dequeque function in the functions.php isn't removing the styles from the plugin "Calculated Fields Form". How can I remove these styles from my page?

My function:

```
// Remove CFF Styles
function remove_calcform_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_stylepublic' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_jquery_ui' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_template_csscp_cff_11' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_calcform_styles', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Calculated Form fields plugin `wp_enqueue_style` used directly, that's why when you add hook for the `wp_enqueue_scripts` nothing happens.

Try to add hook for the `init` action:

```
function remove_calcform_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_stylepublic' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_jquery_ui' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'cpcff_template_csscp_cff_11' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_calcform_styles', 10 );
```

**UPDATE**

Try also `plugins_loaded` action:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_calcform_styles', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that's not the solution, it still loads all styles